# Phpmailer oauth2 - expert needed

Tags: php, oauth, phpmailer

I'm trying this with phpmailer 6. I want to connect with the auth token **without negotiating the refresh token** within phpmailer. I will handle the error myself and ask for the expired token if necessary. Here is my code.

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;   
require_once('PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php');
require_once('PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php');
require_once('PHPMailer/src/Exception.php');

    $FROM_EMAIL = 'xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com';
    $FROM_NAME  = 'name';
    $SMTP_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $SMTP_ENCRYPTION = 'ssl';
    $SMTP_PORT = '465'; 
$TOKEN = "ya29.Il-8B-B3c7F-TdeiLV4RfK4RD_zchewnOerrZPdH8D3wJmVZwrwOQr8Wrx7R0IJsoTS5Lg5OIcX424suheD_RI6cZ-qvV6SCtGV_2trVM7xg1PaVXqMWouRavv2HnHyCcA";

try {  
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);      
$mail->AuthType = 'XOAUTH2';
$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;   
$mail->isSMTP();            
$mail->Host = $SMTP_HOST; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;         
$mail->SMTPSecure = $SMTP_ENCRYPTION;   
$mail->Port = $SMTP_PORT;   
$tokenbase46 = base64_encode(
            'user=' .
            $FROM_EMAIL .
            "\001auth=Bearer " .
            $TOKEN .
            "\001\001"  );  

$mail->addCustomHeader('Authorization', $tokenbase46 ); 
$mail->smtpConnect();

}
catch (Exception $e) {
  $err = $e->errorMessage(); 
}
```

Error!

```
2020-01-30 20:00:48 Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465, timeout=300, options=array()
2020-01-30 20:00:48 Connection: opened
2020-01-30 20:00:48 SMTP INBOUND: "220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP x14sm7412178wmj.42 - gsmtp"
2020-01-30 20:00:48 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP x14sm7412178wmj.42 - gsmtp
2020-01-30 20:00:48 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2020-01-30 20:00:48 SMTP INBOUND: "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [88.16.61.281]"
2020-01-30 20:00:48 SMTP INBOUND: "250-SIZE 35882577"
2020-01-30 20:00:48 SMTP INBOUND: "250-8BITMIME"
2020-01-30 20:00:48 SMTP INBOUND: "250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH"
2020-01-30 20:00:48 SMTP INBOUND: "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
2020-01-30 20:00:48 SMTP INBOUND: "250-PIPELINING"
2020-01-30 20:00:48 SMTP INBOUND: "250-CHUNKING"
2020-01-30 20:00:48 SMTP INBOUND: "250 SMTPUTF8"
2020-01-30 20:00:48 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [88.16.61.281]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2020-01-30 20:00:48 Auth method requested: XOAUTH2
2020-01-30 20:00:48 Auth methods available on the server: LOGIN,PLAIN,XOAUTH2,PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN,OAUTHBEARER,XOAUTH
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2020-01-30 20:00:48 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2020-01-30 20:00:48 SMTP INBOUND: "221 2.0.0 closing connection x14sm7412178wmj.42 - gsmtp"
2020-01-30 20:00:48 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection x14sm7412178wmj.42 - gsmtp
2020-01-30 20:00:48 Connection: closed
```

**UPDATE**

I changed Smtp.php

```
    case 'XOAUTH2': 
    if (null === $OAuth) { 
//return false; 
} 
    $oauth = base64_encode( 'user=' . $FROM_EMAIL . "\001auth=Bearer " . $TOKEN . "\001\001" );
```

Result: The auth string is passed but with a new error

```
2020-01-31 13:37:52 Auth methods available on the server: LOGIN,PLAIN,XOAUTH2,PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN,OAUTHBEARER,XOAUTH 
2020-01-31 13:37:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH XOAUTH2 dXNlcj1BXmF1dGg9QmVhcmVyIEFeQV4= 
2020-01-31 13:37:52 SMTP INBOUND: "501 5.5.2 Cannot Decode response a198sm10442370wme.12 - gsmtp"
```

Comment: You're definitely swimming upstream here! For it to fail like that, it must be reaching [this point](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/SMTP.php#L550). That's no surprise when you have not created an `OAuth` instance - PHPMailer itself does not have an `oauthToken` property. Have you read [the gmail XOAUTH2 example script](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail_xoauth.phps)? There's [a script to help you get the tokens too](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/get_oauth_token.php).

Comment: I have the token. All there depends on requesting the access token with the refresh token with google  client id and client secret. I just want to login using the stored token. I'm lost. I want to make phpmailer login an that's it :(

Comment: I see what you mean, but auth tokens expire, so you need a refresh token and a mechanism to use it too. You can't put it in a message header - this isn't HTTP. I suspect the way to go would be to inject a subclass of the OAuth class that allows you to store an auth token manually, and return it directly rather than using the regeneration functions implicit in using the league packages. For the record, I find OAuth horribly confusing too...

Comment: I guess I need to change the smtpConnect function to allow sending the oauth string, but how?

Comment: That will happen if you do what I suggested - create a child class of the OAuth class and inject it into PHPMailer, then `$OAuth` will not be `null`, and when it subsequently calls the `getOauth64()` method, you can return your auth token directly (like what you're doing with `$tokenbase46`) rather than asking the provider to generate it.